# Register Windows Service by Wix Tool Set script

Tags: c#, wix, windows-services, wix3.9

I have Wix setup project which configure windows service to auto-start on install and system reboot. Before auto-start feature, everything was fine. My procedure of deployment was to install service, register it via "InstallUtil.exe" utility and then start service manual. I want to automate all these activities, but I am facing a problem when i try to install service on a system on which service is not configured with "InstallUtil.exe" utility. The error message I am getting is given as:

> Service "(ServiceName) could not be configured. This could be problem
>   with the package or your permissions. Verify that you have sufficient
>   privileges to configure system services.

Service configuration code is:

```
 <ServiceInstall Id="ServiceInstaller" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes"         Name="$(var.ServiceName)" DisplayName="$(var.ServiceName)" Description="Description" 
                            Start="auto" Account="LocalSystem" ErrorControl="normal" Interactive="no"/>
          <ServiceConfig Id="ServiceConfigAtStartUp" ServiceName="$(var.ServiceName)" DelayedAutoStart="yes" OnInstall="yes" OnReinstall ="yes" />
            <ServiceControl Id="StartService" Name="$(var.ServiceName)" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Wait="yes" />
```

Comment: Are you sure the service isn't already installed on this system? I kept getting this error message when doing some tests and it turned out a service with the same name was already installed on the system.

Comment: Yes, I am sure, service with the same name is not already installed on the system. Now I have a separate project which register's Windows service to the system. I will call this executable at the end of installation to register Windows service if not already registered. I am not sure it is a good way or not.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Edgar Jul. This problem has been solved. I wrote a small console project in C# which registers Windows service if not already registered. This is very easy in C#. I call this executable (ServiceRegister.exe) as a custom action after all the installation files are copied, as can be be seen in the following Wix script.

```
    <CustomAction Id="RegisterService"
              Directory="INSTALLFOLDER"
              ExeCommand="&quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]ServiceRegister.exe&quot; /Register"
              Execute="deferred"
              Return="ignore"
              Impersonate="no" />
<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action='RegisterService' After='InstallFiles' />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```